# jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class Sample not found

Tags: python-2.7, jpype

I am using following code Snippet to invoke the function present in jar file. but i am unable to connect the class.

```
Development Env:
Python: Python27,32bit jpype Version(JPype-0.5.4.2.win32-py2.7.exe)
Java:  jre1.8.0_60,32bit.
```

Java Code:

```
public class Samp {

     public Samp() {
        super();
    }
    public String sayHi()
    {
        return("Hello");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println ("Hello world");
    }

    public static int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }
}
```

**C:\temp\tem\samp.jar** Jar file is presen in that directory. I am Connecting jar file using below code.

python Code:

```
>>import jpype
>>jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), '-ea', '-     Djava.class.path=c:\\temp\\tem')
>>A = jpype.JClass("Samp")
>>a = Samp()
>>print a.sayHi()
>>jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

By running above code,I am getting following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype_jclass.py", line
>   54, in JClass
>       raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name) jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class Samp
>   not found

Answer (score 0):

At the fourth row you want to do

```
>>> a = A()
```

and then

```
>>> print a.sayHi()
```

Comment: Thanks cpburnz, I had used the syntax of the question. :-)